# PIG - Get Highest & Lowest Medal Winning Nations , GROUPed by Year

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

- Pretty new to Pig , I have a dataset which consists of Olympics data
  for 4-5 years. I am trying to generate highest and lowest medal
  winning countries split by every year.  Hers's a sample with header.

  **ATHLETE,COUNTRY,YEAR, SPORT,GOLD,SILVER,BRONZE,TOTAL**

  ```
  Yang Yilin,China,2008,Gymnastics,1,0,2,3  
  Leisel Jones,Australia,2000,Swimming,0,2,0,2  
  Go Gi-Hyeon,South Korea,2002,Short-Track Speed Skating,1,1,0,2  
  Chen Ruolin,China,2008,Diving,2,0,0,2  
  Katie Ledecky,United States,2012,Swimming,1,0,0,1  
  Ruta Meilutyte,Lithuania,2012,Swimming,1,0,0,1  
  DÃ¡niel Gyurta,Hungary,2004,Swimming,0,1,0,1  
  Arianna Fontana,Italy,2006,Short-Track Speed Skating,0,0,1,1  
  Olga Glatskikh,Russia,2004,Rhythmic Gymnastics,1,0,0,1  
  Kharikleia Pantazi,Greece,2000,Rhythmic Gymnastics,0,0,1,1
  ```
- I tried my options as per my knowledge to get this , but with little
  sucess.
  This is what i have now.  Any help on solving this will be
  appreciated !

  ```
  DEFINE MYOVER org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over;    
  DEFINE MYSTITCH org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch; 

  A = LOAD 'MortDataSite/MyPigExercise/OlympicMedals.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (ATHLETE:CHARARRAY,COUNTRY:CHARARRAY,YEAR:INT,SPORT:CHARARRAY,GOLD:INT,SILVER:INT,BRONZE:INT,TOTAL:INT);
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE YEAR,COUNTRY,TOTAL;  
  C = GROUP B BY (YEAR,COUNTRY);  
  D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (YEAR,COUNTRY) ,SUM(B.TOTAL);   
  E = GROUP D BY (YEAR,COUNTRY);  
  F = FOREACH E { 
           E1 = ORDER D BY TOT DESC;
           GENERATE FLATTEN(MYSTITCH(E1, MYOVER(E1,'dense_rank',0,1,1))); 
           }; 

  G = FOREACH F GENERATE stitched::YEAR,stitched::COUNTRY ,stitched::TOT,$3;
  ```

  **MyOutput :**    ( Considering there are many nations with same TOTAL Medals
  , I expect more than one country may share one RANK )

  ```
  (2000,Cuba,65,1)    
  (2000,Iran,4,1)    
  (2000,Chile,17,1)    
  (2000,China,79,1)    
  (2000,India,7,1)    
  (2000,Italy,65,1)    
  (2000,Japan,42,1)    
  (2000,Kenya,7,1)   
  (2000,Qatar,1,1)   
  (2000,Spain,42,1)   
  (2000,Brazil,48,1)
  ```

**Expected Ouput :   1**

```
YEAR COUNTRY MAX(TOTAL)       
2001 India  50  
2003 UK     90   
2006 Japan  56
```

&

**Expected Ouput :   2**

```
YEAR COUNTRY MIN(TOTAL)
2001 India  5   
2003 UK     10   
2006 Japan  6
```

********* Updated Query  ( Working Well as expected ) ****

- Here's the updated query which gave me my desired result.

  ```
  DEFINE MYOVER org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over;    
  DEFINE MYSTITCH org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch; 

  A = LOAD 'MortDataSite/MyPigExercise/OlympicMedals.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (ATHLETE:CHARARRAY,COUNTRY:CHARARRAY,YEAR:INT,SPORT:CHARARRAY,GOLD:INT,SILVER:INT,BRONZE:INT,TOTAL:INT);
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE YEAR,COUNTRY,TOTAL;  
  C = GROUP B BY (YEAR,COUNTRY);  
  D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (YEAR,COUNTRY) ,SUM(B.TOTAL);   
  E = GROUP D BY (YEAR,COUNTRY); 
  F = FOREACH E GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (YEAR,COUNTRY) ,MAX(D.TOT) as MTOT;
  G = GROUP F BY YEAR;
  H = FOREACH G {
              G1 = ORDER F BY MTOT DESC;
              GENERATE FLATTEN(MYSTITCH(G1, MYOVER(G1,'dense_rank',0,1,1))); 
                };
       J = FOREACH H GENERATE stitched::YEAR,stitched::COUNTRY ,stitched::MTOT,$3;
  ```

**Ouput :   **
    YEAR COUNTRY MAX(TOTAL).RANKING
    (2000,United States,242,1)
    (2000,Russia,187,2)
    (2000,Australia,182,3)
    (2002,United States,84,1)
    (2002,Canada,74,2)
    (2002,Germany,61,3)
    (2004,United States,265,1)
    (2004,Russia,190,2)
    (2004,Australia,156,3)

Comment: what do you get as output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to get the MAX and MIN total medals by country by year,just use MAX and MIN.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE YEAR,COUNTRY,TOTAL;  
C = GROUP B BY (YEAR,COUNTRY);  
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (YEAR,COUNTRY) ,SUM(B.TOTAL) as TOTAL;   
E = GROUP D BY (YEAR,COUNTRY);    
F = FOREACH E GENERATE group as  (YEAR,COUNTRY),MAX(D.TOTAL);
G = FOREACH E GENERATE group as  (YEAR,COUNTRY),MIN(D.TOTAL);
DUMP F;
DUMP G;
```

Comment: Hey ,am looking for something additional. 
If we observe the sample data , every row has info about individual athlete. The code you provided calulates MAX & MIN of Column : TOTAL.

What i need is ,  MAX & MIN COUNT of MEDAL TALLY for a specific country split by years.


For that initailly we should GROUP BY YEAR,COUNTRY & calculate the SUM(TOTAL) ---- > This will give us TOTAL MEDALS earned by a country in that specific year.
Later on,  we will need to RANK this SUM(TOTAL) and generate MAX & MIN medals , PARTITION BY  year. --- > I am not able to figure out how to implement this one !

Comment: @San Why do you need to rank it? Can't you apply the max and min on the total?

Comment: Hey , I was able to pull off my needs here. thanks for correcting my question layouts.. With some ideas from your query , I have updated my query with output. 

Only problem exist is  : IF i apply 
I = FILTER H BY $3 == 1; 
throws "Cannot cast bytearray to chararray" . 
I see thats  fixes in higher versions of PIG. Mine is  version 0.12.

Do You have any suggetions on fixing that error ? If tha succeds , we can filter nations on POSTITON (RANK) =1 , 2 , 3 etc ..

Comment: @San You will get that error if the datatype is not known for the field.Check datatype of $3,most likely the datatype is not specified for that field.

Comment: $3 is run  time generated by dense_rank inbuilt function. Therefore , i am not able to recall a way to define its datatype. Any suggestions there?  I tried many ways to define a datatype to it , but no success.